# Display Web Application resources through the web browser

Tags: java, model-view-controller, rss

i implemented a small web application to create Rss feeds in java(spring mvc)

i created a page within the application where i display all the Rss(xml files) created

this occur reading into the folder where the rss are stored (the Rss are obviously in xml format)

the rss path looks like

C:\Documents and Settings\Giga\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaRssFeed\RssFeed\build\web\WEB-INF\Xml\title.xml

The root of the application is RssFeed(in the browser i usually type http://localhost:8080/RssFeed/home.htm for the home page)

the question is

how can i display the feeds into the browser?

In IE i can use the path

C:\Documents and Settings\Giga\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaRssFeed\RssFeed\build\web\WEB-INF\Xml\title.xml

but it doesn t work in Firefox

i tried to do something like

http://localhost:8080/RssFeed/xml/title.xml

but i get source not found error

the question is how can i display the rss feeds into the browser?

Comment: You should really read the most basic getting started guide before posting a question like this...  All application resources should be accessed through the URL context, not the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should have a running web server (tomcat, was, etc)
2. Deploy the app and access it via http://localhost:8080/YOURAPP